# ANCS Android device cannot be found from iOS bluetooth Settings

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ancs

I am advertising ANCS service from an Android phone (Samsung Galaxy S6) in peripheral mode. I can find the service from iOS apps like LightBlue. However I cannot find my Android phone from bluetooth search settings page.
I would like to pair to the Android BLE Peripheral phone from the settings page of the iOS device. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you trying to receive notifications from the iOS device on your Android device or do you want to send notifications from the Android device?

Comment: I managed to get the notifications from the iOS device via ANCS. I have an Android device in peripheral mode. The iphone finds the Android device that's advertising, connects to it and then the Android device connects back to the iPhone (asking for bounding if it has not been bounded yet), scans for its services and subscribes to ANCS characteristics. It all works fine until I try to reconnect. iPhone then changes MAC address and the pairing is gone. I was wondering if starting pairing from iPhone bluetooth settings would create a bound that will last forever. But I cannot find my And device.

Comment: Have you specified encryption required for one of your service characteristics?  This will create a bonding between the two devices. you cannot initiate bonding with a BLE device from the iOS settings screen, only legacy devices

Comment: Have you tried simply having the iOS app operate as the peripheral?  Then you can connect from your Android in central mode rather than having to switch roles.

Comment: ANCS on the iPhone side already requires authorized access.. but it did not trigger any bonding request when connecting to it from the Android phone. It justs disconnects the moment I try to write to the data source descriptor to enable notifications.

Comment: In our setup the Android device will accept Gatt connections from both iOS devices and Android devices. It must behave as the peripheral (and then reconnect back to whoever is calling) because not all the Android phones can work in peripheral mode.

Comment: @HéctorJúdezSapena did you figure this out?